# Google Maps api

Tags: google-maps

I have to provide such functionality:

User checks 2-10 cities at Google Maps, I count the way between those cities using roads and show the way. The additional information is length of the full way.

Is it possible with google maps?

Comment: You're basically giving us the spec and asking for 'teh codez'. What have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: @sergio-boombastic I used another map engine and I know how to work with it. Now I have a request for google maps and I don't know is that functionality possible there. I don't want to spend my time for reading it. If it's not available I'll use my old map engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know the order you want to be travelling to the cities in, then you just have to make a DirectionsRequest using the in between cities as waypoints. If you don't know the order, as long as you know the start and end, you can have Google Maps optimize the order of the waypoints for you.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Waypoints